# How to move tables in MS SQL Server 2012 (Developer) to a web hosting company?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, cloud

I am about to start making a small e-commerce website using ASP.NET, C# and SQL Server 2012.
However before I start, I would like to learn how to make the transition from a local DB to a web hosting DB. I looked at http://www.hostgator.com/windows-hosting and they have Microsoft SQL listed under their options. I read some reviews and they seem to be one the best web hosting companies around, and their customer service was quite good last time I talked to them(regarding a different issue).

I would go straight to their "live chat" again, but I am pretty sure those Level 1 support wouldn't really be able to help me. I also looked at https://somee.com/default.aspx as a free web hosting alternative for testing and what not.

Anyways, if someone could shed some light on this matter I would really appreciate it. Other web hosting companies are welcomed, I also thought about MS Azure, but I don't have much experience with cloud computing so there is still some research that I have to do on that front.

PS: These are the tools that I will use to get the job done(as of now) and what I would like to accomplish.

Tools:

1. SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition
2. Visual Studio 2012 (C# and ASP.NET)

Goals for my website:

1. Log-in System
2. Account System
3. Shopping Cart
4. PayPal
5. Some sort of schedule/web calendar tool

Comment: What problem are you having? Create the DB in their system, get the connection string... and use it. Can edit your web.config to use your connection string in debug mode, and the other in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

first take a look does the hosting company have SQL 2012 in offer.

My first attempt would be : 
- Make Database backup on local server and try to use ISP tool for database, I'm sure that they have some DB tools that support 'Restore' option.

Second :
- They would give you SQL login data, You can write some little code for synchronization. Read from one database and send the data to ISP server. This code should be run on Your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Azure, so I thought I would also point out that Azure Websites has a gallery of eCommerce packages that you can install. I believe all of these have the key capabilities you are looking at.

Some of the packages you can quickly install are:

- Drupal Commerce Kickstart
- Kentico CMS for ASP.NET
- mojoPortal
- nopCommerce
- OpenX

There is a little more information on this here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/